# Unterminated Object at character.. (JSON)

Tags: android, json, facebook

I know this question has been asked many times but I couldn`t find any solution for this one...

i`m trying to get the user facebook likes and check if the user likes my page.

my code:

```
public void checkIfLikes() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        new Request(
                session,
                "/" + user_ID + "/likes",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                        String likesJson = response.toString();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        try {
                            jsonObject = new JSONObject(likesJson);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject idObjects = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = idObjects.getString("id");
                                if (id.equals("192157224142472")) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
```

Now I get this error when it runs:

> 04-28 00:34:23.140: W/System.err(18946): org.json.JSONException:
>   Unterminated object at character 25 of {Response:  responseCode: 200,
>   graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject,
>   state={"data":[{"created_time":"2015-04-27T20:46:22+0000","id":"463197940498665","category":"Community
>   organization","name":"Pitch Tonight"},{"id":"753310168023547"...

It seems to me I`m getting it right and the JSON string looks good to me aswell. 
Would like some help and sorry if this question was posted. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the actual JSON is the value of the "state" field from your server response, and you are parsing the full server response as a JSON. That might be the problem.

Comment: Thank you! was able to get only the data by this line:
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");